# Guidance on configuring/testing SSO progrimatically

Tags: azure, powershell, single-sign-on

I would like to configure SSO for Azure enterprise applications programmatically.

I am having some difficulty finding the relevant documentation.

Specifically these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-portal

1. Configure with PS
2. test with PS as applicable

If someone can point me to the correct docs, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I researched on it but unable to find a specific documentation. The below documentation can help you to start with power shell for Single sign on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-sso#manual-reset-of-the-feature

I hope this helps.